# PyQt : Updating Custom List Widget Item in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I was able to add custom QListWidgetItem in QListWidget using the following code -

```
for item in dl_list:            
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        card = Ui_DownloadCard()
        card.setupUi(widget)
        card.set_filename(item["title"])
        card.set_progress_bar(item["progress"])
        card.set_progress_text(item["progress"]/item["size"])
        card.set_speed(item["speed"])

        listItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.download_list)
        listItem.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())

        self.myListWidget.addItem(listItem)
        self.myListWidget.setItemWidget(listItem, widget)
```

Now I wish to update each item with new speed & progress. I tried the following code -

`self.myListWidget.item(0).set_speed("300 KB/s")`

But it gives error saying

`AttributeError: 'QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'set_speed'`

So what is the correct way to update the item?

Comment: How are we supposed to know that when you don't show us what `download_list` is? Consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you say you are using a  `custom QListWidgetItem` if the item you use is the one that comes by default, ie QListWidgetItem?

Answer (score 0):

```
listItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.download_list)
```

you need use your custom item instead:

```
listItem = YourCustomListWidgetItem(self.download_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

From specs: 
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget

QListWidget.setItemWidget

This function should only be used to display static content in the place of a list widget item. If you want to display custom dynamic content or implement a custom editor widget, use QListView and subclass QItemDelegate instead.

So if you want to work with dynamic components it's necessary to use QListView and subclass QItemDelegate instead.